# swapping inside the list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

Suppose that I have two lists that contain the following elements.
i.e.

```
l1 = ['a','b','c']
l2 = [1,2,3]
```

each element of `l1` is related to the corresponding element in `l2` at the same index. The relation is such that if the user enters the list `l1` the output is `l2`.Suppose if the user enters a list such as `['a','c','b']` then the output should be `[1,3,2]`.
How can I do the following function ? The easier way is to use a dictionary that corresponds each element of `l1` to that of `l2` .But I am looking for a better method, if not then a smaller code ..
Another example (Just In Case)

```
l1 = ['c','b','a']
l2 = [3,2,1]
```

Comment: A dict is easy: `dict(zip(l1,l2)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want them to line up as follows:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  ...
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 ...
```

You should define a dictionary to do this, like you said. You can either use `dict(zip(...))`:

```
def get_nums(lst):
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' # also string.ascii_lowercase
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
               17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26] # range(1, 27)
    mapping = dict(zip(letters,numbers))
    return [mapping[lett] for lett in lst]
```

Or you could just use `enumerate` for this

```
def get_nums(lst):
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' # also string.ascii_lowercase
    mapping = {lett:idx for idx,lett in enumerate(letters, start=1)}
    return [mapping[lett] for lett in lst]
```

As [castle-bravo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2738025/castle-bravo) points out, for this naive mapping you can use something like:

```
def get_nums(lst):
    return [ord(lett) - 96 for lett in lst]
```

But this isn't very scalable to other mappings, and can cause unexpected issues if your input isn't rigorously defined.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [list.index()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

```
>>> l1 = ['a','b','c']
>>> l2 = [1,2,3]
>>> l3 = ['c','b','a']
>>> l4 = []
>>> for item in l3:
...     l4.append(l2[l1.index(item)])
>>> l4
[3, 2, 1]
```

iterate over the l3 (user input), to get the index of the item on l1, use this index to retrieve the value on l2, and append the value on l4

Comment: But I want to output a list, not an individual element

Comment: I don't get it. give the input `l1 = ['c','b','a']` and `l2 = [3,2,1]` , what should be the output???

Comment: @Rod directly from the question: "if the user enters a list such as `['a','c','b']` then the output should be `[1,3,2]`"

Answer (score 0):

In pure Python, try:

```
l2[l1.index('b')]
```

As a function, this would look like:

```
def lookup(element, l1, l2):
    return l2[l1.index(element)]
```

You could complicate this even further if you want, by adding a class wrapper around list, and some error handling and so on, but I don't know if it's worth it or not.

Comment: OP has input of `['a','b','c']` and wants output of `[1,2,3]`. This doesn't do that.

Comment: OP's question wasn't clear, but I see what you mean.

He really wants `ord(l1[i]) - 96`.

Comment: "if the user enters a list such as `['a','c','b']` then the output should be `[1,3,2]`." Seemed clear to me! Yes, `[ord(lett)-96 for lett in l1]` should work.

Comment: How Pythonic! I was about to advise him to do something with defs.